# JWPlayer causing black borders around video

Tags: video, jwplayer

I'm getting stuck between two scenarios with JWPlayer for a video:

1) With a correct aspect ratio the video is only loading in half the available width
[image: Scenario one problem]

2) If I increase the available height I end up with borders top and bottom (which makes sense as the ratio is no longer correct: live example: http://goo.gl/nfTIzW!

Here is the code being used:

```
<div class="video-container">
     <script>jwplayer.key="xxx"</script>
     <div id="container<?php echo $id; ?>">Loading the player ...</div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer('container<?php echo $id; ?>').setup({
                        modes:
                            [
                                { type: "flash", src: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf' },
                                { type: "html5" }
                            ],
                        skin: '/jwplayer/modieus.xml',
                        controlbar: "over",
                        'controlbar.idlehide': "true",
                        aspectratio: "16:9",
                        file: '<?php echo $video; ?>',
                        image: '<?php echo $image; ?>',
                        height: '100%',
                        width: '100%'
                    });
    </script>
</div>

.video-container
{
     display:relative;
     width:592px;
     height:333px;
     margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

So the height and width is 100% in order to use media queries on the video-container, 592 x 333 is a correct 16:9 aspect ratio but only plays half width, increased height uses most the available height but ends up with black borders. Any suggestions?

Though I don't believe I *should* need to, I've tried using the 'stretching' attribute as 'fill', which does fix scenario one until a different media query kicks in and then half the video disappears.

Comment: Have you tried to use stretching=exactfit?

Comment: Yes, I've tried all the other stretching options and none fix either scenario. If I use exactfit to fix the black borders, it goes back to only using half the screen...

Comment: The issue appears to be that the video is trying to scale, if I had the following code it uses the full screen again, but this is obviously a hack and it looks as though the quality isn't 100% `.jwvideo video
{
    /*
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    height:100% !important;
    width:100% !important;*/
}`

Comment: What if primary is set to flash?

Comment: This does fix scenario 1! Though only with people who have flash (thus not most tablets etc) so not an all round solution but narrows the problem down to HTML5!

Comment: In regards to html5, have you tried to embed the player itself on a blank html page alone, to test?

Comment: Has there been a resolution to this? I am having a similar issue where the video is shrunk to the middle of the player.